# Deleting a node in double linked list by an index position

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete a node from a doubly-linked list, but I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to delete the 2nd item. I was able to delete the first item and the last item.

Below is my code:

```
@Override
public T removeElement(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    T result = null;

    if (IsEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    if (count == 1 && index == 0) {
        result = head.getData();
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        result = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
    }
    if (count == index) {
        result = tail.getData();
        tail = tail.getPrev();
        tail.setNext(null);
    }
    int i = 1;
    for (Node<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
        if (i == index){
            result = current.getData();
            Node<T> previous = current.getPrev();
            Node<T> next = current.getNext();
            previous.setNext(next);
            next.setPrev(previous); //getting null pointer exception here
        }
        i++;
    }

    count--;
    return result;
}

@Override
public void addElement(T data)//add elements in the list
{
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (IsEmpty()) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode.setPrev(tail);
        tail.setNext(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Here is my test program:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleListImpl<Integer> test = new DoubleListImpl<Integer>();

    test.addElement(10);
    test.addElement(20);
    test.addElement(40);
    test.addElement(50);
    test.display();
    System.out.println(test.getCount());
    test.removeElement(4);
    System.out.println();
    //test.removeElement(3);
    test.display();
    System.out.println(test.getCount());
}
}
```

UPDATE:

I noticed something interesting a minute ago. If i made `i=0` i get a null pointer error when i pass `index ==3` as an argument in the removeElement function. or when i make i=1 i get a null pointer when i pass `i==2` as an argument.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but it appears that the condition `if(count==index)` for detecting deletion of the last element is wrong.  Elsewhere your code shows that you are indexing from zero, so if `count` is the number of elements in the list then the index of the last element is `count - 1`.

Comment: Do check again this `if ( index == 0 )` condition. Here no doubt, you moving `head` to point to the next node in sequence, though, you never did made the `previous` of current `head` to be `null`, since the first node has been deleted, and now the `head` has moved ahead, but it's previous must be `null` now.

Comment: The count variable confused me, where did you initialise it?

Comment: More generally, you don't seem to trap attempts to delete elements having out-of-range indices, except when the list is empty.

Comment: Does `Node.setNext()` or `Node.setPrevious()` do *anything* other than assign the argument to the appropriate field of the object upon which it is invoked?

Comment: Suggestion: give your list internal, permanent dummy nodes to serve as the true head and tail (they can even be the same object), so that all the *real* nodes are internal.  You can then avoid writing special cases for the first and last real elements and for single-element lists.

Comment: The normal-case deletion loop deletes the wrong element when you initialize `i = 1`.  And take `head` as the first `current`.  One fix would be to take `head.getNext()` as the first `current`; another would be to initialize `i` to `0` instead of to `1`.

Comment: All of the foregoing notwithstanding, my best guess is that `DoubleListImpl.addElement()` does not correctly initialize new nodes' `next` references, at least in some cases.  You can check for this and many other possibilities by running your test program in a debugger.

Comment: @pk163 i intialized count in the constructor class

Comment: You've got at least 2 bugs: 1. add 1 node, then retrieve it. You'll get an NPE in your 2nd if block.  2. retrieve the tail by setting index==count. (see @John Bollinger's message above).  Your NPE in the current code stems from assuming next is always set--it isn't. Fix those problems, and then fix the case where you're retrieving the tail (and thus, next isn't set).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote in comments that I didn't think the erroneous `if(count==index)` was the cause of the NPE.  I see now that it isn't *directly* the problem, but it does *contribute* to the problem by not catching the case where you request to delete the actual last node (index `count - 1`).

Of course, your `addElement()` method does not set or increment `count` when a node is added and `IsEmpty()` initially returns `true`, so the count will also be *wrong*.  In fact, if `IsEmpty()` depends on `count` to determine whether the list is empty then `addElement()` will never expand your list past one element -- new elements "added" will instead replace the previous one.

Also contributing is the fact that execution falls through to the loop at the end of your method even when deletion has already been accomplished via one of the earlier special cases, as I also observed already.  Consider, then, what happens when `index` is exactly the right value for the loop to iterate up to, but not beyond, the last element in your list.  Control enters the block conditioned on `i == index`, and the current element's previous and next elements are retrieved.  But the element in question is *the last one*, so its `next` is `null`.  When you attempt to invoke `setPrev()` on that null reference, an NPE results.

I reiterate my suggestion in comments that you add internal `Node` objects to serve as head and tail, so that the Nodes containing real data are all internal, and you don't need all the special cases.  For example,

```
class DoubleListImpl<T> implements DoubleList<T> {

    private final Node<T> head = new Node<T>(null);

    {   // better to put this in a constructor, but this way I avoid writing any
        head.setNext(head);
        head.setPrev(head);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public T removeElement(int index) {
        int i = 0;

        // negative indexes are always invalid
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        for (Node<T> current = head.getNext(); current != head;
                current = current.getNext()) {
            if (i == index){
                Node<T> previous = current.getPrev();
                Node<T> next = current.getNext();

                previous.setNext(next);
                next.setPrev(previous);
                // maybe you need count for something else, but not for this
                // count -= 1;
                return current.getData();
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        // If control reaches here then the given index is invalid
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help i really appreciate it. Your input guided me. I posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys thanks for the input. I actually figured out my error and this works. Below is my solution to the problem. Thanks a lot guys for the help:

```
@Override
public T removeElement(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    T result = null;
    assert(index>=1&&index<=count);

    if(index==1){
        if(count==1){
            result = head.getData();
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
        else{
            result = head.getData();
            head = head.getNext();
            head.setPrev(null);
        }
    }
    else if(index==count){
        result = tail.getData();
        tail = tail.getPrev();
        tail.setNext(null);
    }
    else{
        Node<T> current = head;
        int i=1;
        while(current!=null){
            if(i==index){
                Node<T> prev = current.getPrev();
                Node<T> next = current.getNext();
                prev.setNext(next);
                next.setPrev(prev);
                break;
                //current = null;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
            i++;
        }
    }   
    count--;
    return result;   
}
```